# CloudFront error 504 after creating "/*" invalidation in order to update S3 static website

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

would appreciate any insight or help on this.

To preface, I am a bit new to AWS and the goal was to host a static website (written in Angular if that matters) for a school project.

Current configs/setup below:

Godaddy for my domain example.com

Route 53, added NS records AWS specified within Godaddy

A certificate within Certificate Manager. Two CNAME records AWS specified were added to Route 53, CNAME records NOT added to Godaddy

TWO s3 buckets, one being example.com and the other [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is configured just to route to example.com. index.html and other dist files for JS and CSS added to example.com bucket and NOT [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) bucket.

A CloudFront distribution in order to serve HTTPS requests to https://www.example.com or https://example.com. Right now it is just configured to redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Yesterday evening, everything was working great. HTTPS was working, HTTP redirected to HTTPS, and I had some friends test the site from different parts of the world - everything was perfect.

What went wrong was I needed to update the code to the website after we made some changes, and push to the example.com bucket. I used @jefiozie/ngx-aws-deploy to deploy from VScode into AWS s3 bucket.

The new code was successfully updated within example.com s3 bucket, but I noticed it did not take effect when accessing the website. When accessing the s3 default bucket endpoint, still no update to the website.

After research on stack overflow and some subreddits, people recommended completing an invalidation to CloudFront in order to fetch the new updates to the s3 bucket with the object path "/*"

After completion, nothing was working. HTTP and HTTPS requests to example.com AND [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) led to a 504 error: the request could not be satisfied. HOWEVER, the s3 default bucket endpoint did still work (without the updates to the website though).

At the time of writing, still there is a 504 error. Interestingly, the s3 default bucket endpoint DID pick up the updates, and the website is up to date with the changes we made to the code last night. This leaves me to believe it may have something to do with a TTL config somewhere in s3?

How can I fix the cloud front distribution in order to get HTTPS requests back to the s3 bucket?

How should I best optimize pushing changes to the s3 bucket to avoid problems like this in the future?

And what configurations should I make to any of the services?

After research on stack overflow and some subreddits, people recommended completing an invalidation to CloudFront in order to fetch the new updates to the s3 bucket with the object path "/*"

After completion, nothing was working. HTTP and HTTPS requests to example.com AND [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) led to a 504 error: the request could not be satisfied. HOWEVER, the s3 default bucket endpoint did still work (without the updates to the website though).

Answer (score 0):

You may have already figured this out, but I ran into this same issue just today and was able to resolve it by what I would consider "resetting" the origin. I selected my origin, selected **edit**, then **cleared out the Origin Domain** and then **re-selected the S3 Bucket Website Endpoint and saved**. Once it deployed, I was able to access without an issue.